# Assign values or string to a variable in linux scripting

Tags: linux, bash-scripting

I am trying to assign the output of the `basename` command of a file to the variable "filename". `paths` is a file that contains the path location, e.g `/root/home/david/mynote`

`$FILE` is = `mynote`. `grep` is to get the full path `/root/home/david/mynote` and 
`basename` is to extract only the `mynote` and assign it to the variable `filename`.

```
filename=basename `grep $FILE House/paths`
```

With the above command line, the value of `filename` is always empty when I enter 
`echo $filename`.

Answer (score 2):

In general, in BASH you save the output of commands to a variable in one of these ways:

```
foo=$(ls /usr)
```

or

```
foo=`ls /usr`
```

---

As for your question, if you have a file called `foo.txt` whose contents look like this:

```
/usr/
/usr/games
/usr/games/cowthink
/usr/games/cowsay
/usr/games/fortune
/usr/games/enemylines7
/usr/games/enemylines3
/usr/lib32
/usr/lib32/libgdbm_compat.so.3.0.0
/usr/lib32/libfusion-1.2.so.9.0.1
```

then this should do what you need:

```
while read FILE; do filename=`basename "$FILE"`; echo "$filename"; done < foo.txt
```

If, instead, you want to search for a specific pattern (e.g. "mynote") in the file do:

```
grep mynote foo.txt|while read FILE; do filename=`basename "$FILE"`; echo "$filename"; done
```

EXPLANATION:

```
while read FILE; do {something}; done < foo.txt
```

This command reads every line of the file `foo.txt` and saves its contents into the variable `$FILE`. It then executes `{something}` once for each line of the file.

In this case, `{something}` is this command:

```
filename=`basename "$FILE"`; echo "$filename"
```

It one runs `basename` on the contents of variable `$FILE` and saves the result in the variable `$filename`. Notice the quotes (`"`) around `$FILE`, they ensure that the command works for file names containing spaces. Finally it uses `echo` to print the contents of `$filename`.

---

UPDATE:

After seeing your [other question](https://superuser.com/q/513461/151431), I understand what you are trying to do. What you need is this:

```
filename=$(basename `grep $FILE CourseWork/paths`)
```

Comment: or $ filename=$(basename /tmp/foo)

Comment: I want to search for the file-path in with grep in the paths file and the perform the basename "???" then assign it to the variable filename.

Comment: @ibi I saw your other question and understood what you are trying to do. See the (re)updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is a perfect example why you should stop using the <strike>deprecated</strike> backtick syntax in bash:

```
filename=$(basename $(grep $FILE House/paths))
```

See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution

Note, to protect against paths that may contain whitespace, enclose some items in double quotes:

```
filename=$(basename "$(grep "$FILE" House/paths)")
```

---

The reason the variable is empty is this: when the shell sees

```
filename=basename `grep $FILE House/paths`
```

1. the shell first executes the grep command (suppose for illustration the command returns "/foo/bar/myfile")
2. the shell then attempts to *execute* "/foo/bar/myfile", **temporarily** setting the environment variable `filename` with the value `baseline` for the duration of that command -- the shell *does not* contain a `filename` variable.

This is quietly documented in the bash reference under [Environment](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Environment)

> The environment for any simple command or function may be augmented temporarily by prefixing it with parameter assignments, as described in [Shell Parameters](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameters). These assignment statements affect only the environment seen by that command.

Comment: Thanks a million Glenn... !!! Your solution did exactly what I needed.